# Mongodb: find documents where at least one item in an array exists in an array field

Tags: arrays, mongodb, search

This is my data:

```
[
  {
    "_id": 1,
    "name": "Alice",
    "favorites": [
      "apple",
      "banana",
      "cherry"
    ]
  },
  {
    "_id": 2,
    "name": "Bob",
    "favorites": [
      "banana",
      "orange"
    ]
  },
  {
    "_id": 3,
    "name": "Charlie",
    "favorites": [
      "apple",
      "cherry"
    ]
  }
]
```

and I need to find the documents that have for example apple or orange in favorites field.
I know this works:

```
    db.collection.aggregate([
      {
        $match: {
             favorites: {
             $in: [
               "apple",
               "orange"
              ]
         }
        }
      }
    ])
```

also I know how to do it with find().

I need to do it with $match and $expr like:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      $expr: {
        $in: [
          "$favorites",
          [
            "banana",
            "orange"
          ]
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])//Returns no data
```

but returns no result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case you are still keen on working the query with `$expr` operator,

1. `$ne` - Check the result from *1.1* not an empty array.

1.1. `$setIntersection` - Intersect the `favorite` and input array to return an array with intersection.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      $expr: {
        $ne: [
          {
            $setIntersection: [
              "$favorites",
              [
                "banana",
                "orange"
              ]
            ]
          },
          []
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Demo @ Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/zgiIinRtzym)